# Cannot charge a customer that has no active card - Stripe Payment

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to charge already created customer but getting error
"*Cannot charge a customer that has no active card*"

[image]

The card is already added too

[image]

Here is the node.js code I am using to charge the customer

```
const response = await stripe.charges.create({
        'amount': amount,
        'currency': currency,
        'description': title,
        'customer': customer,
    }, { idempotencyKey: onDemandId });






// What I am sending
    {
      "amount": "40",
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": "120 دقيقة",
      "customer": "cus_I33Z2JrUSj1bBm"
    }


// What I am getting
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "missing",
        "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/missing",
        "message": "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card",
        "param": "card",
        "type": "card_error"
      }
    }
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the Customer has a [`default_source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-default_source), and [set it](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-default_source) using [one of their saved cards](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list) if needed.

Even better, you should look at [creating payment using a saved card with Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-create-payment-intent-off-session), and then the answer would be that you need to provide the [`payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-create-payment-intent-off-session) explicitly.